# How can I work out tensions using moments?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, moment

If you were given the weight of a metre rule, its weight and the distance between 2 vertical rods holding it up, how would you work out the tension in the rods using the concept of moments or vectors?

[image: pic]

Ignore my scribbles on the page, apart from the 90, they are probably wrong.  The weight of the rule is 30N.  I have really tried to work this out.  I would assume that the principle of moments applies as it is in equilibrium.  There is no telling if the 30N is smack bang in the middle of the two rods, but if you try that then both tensions would be equal, which they are not.

Any hints on where to go?  Could I apply the concept of moments and F * d to this?

Comment: Is there a 75N load applied on the end?

Comment: No, that was one of my scribbles when I was trying to do the question.

Comment: Please have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583).

Answer (score 1):

You start from a free body diagram. Add all known and unknown forces (including weight) at the appropriate locations.

- Take the net vertical loads and set the value equal to zero.
- Take the net moments about any point and set that value equal to zero.

These two equations need to be solved for the two tensions at the supports.

**For example**:

[image: fbd]

$$ \left. \begin{align} A + B - W & = 0 \\
\frac{\ell}{2} W-a A-(a+b) B & = 0 \end{align} \right\} \begin{aligned} 
 A &= W \left( \frac{2(a+b)-\ell}{2 b} \right) \\
 B &= W \left( \frac{\ell -2 a}{2b} \right)
 \end{aligned} $$